# C++, equality with g++

Tags: c++, g++, equality

```
Why this condition is never true ? Both parts of the equation are integers, so there must be equality for index = 0, 10, 20, 30, 40. I am compiling this code using g++.

for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++){

        if ( (int) (10 * (  0.1 * index)  ==  (int)(10 * ( int ) ( 0.1 * index ) ) ) )
        {
                 std::cout << "equal";
        }
}
```

With MSVS 2010 compiler these problems do not occur...

```
  0  0
  1  0
  2  0
  3  0
  4  0
  5  0
  6  0
  7  0
  8  0
  9  0
  10  10
  11  10
  12  10
  13  10
  14  10
  15  10
  16  10
  17  10
  18  10
  19  10
  20  20
  21  20
  22  20
  23  20
  24  20
  25  20
  26  20
  27  20
  28  20
  29  20
  30  30
  31  30
  32  30
  33  30
  34  30
  35  30
  36  30
  37  30
  38  30
  39  30
  40  40
  41  40
  42  40
  40  40
  44  40
  45  40
  46  40
  47  40
  48  40
  49  40
```

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using? Works for me.

Comment: It's because in the second part of the equality you round the number with "(int)." 

10 * ( int ) ( 0.1 * index ), for 15 it becomes 
10 * (int) (0.1 * 15) which becomes
10 * ((int) 1.5) which becomes
10 * 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong:

```
if ( (int) (10 * (  0.1 * index)  ==  (int)(10 * ( int ) ( 0.1 * index ) ) ) )
```

Should be:

```
if ( (int) (10 * (  0.1 * index) )  ==  (int)(10 * ( int ) ( 0.1 * index ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two floating point numbers - 0.1*index.

Have you tried printing out the individual components when they're *not* equal?  I suspect you'll find that somewhere in the equation, the results vary.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the second part you have  ( int ) ( 0.1 * index ). So (int) (0.1 * 5) becomes rounded to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The two sides are not both integers:

```
10 * (0.1 * index)
```

is a double, and uses `0.1` that as you probably know cannot be represented exactly in IEEE754 format (the only values that can be represented exactly are integral multiples of 1/(2^n) with n>=0). To make a parallel with base 10 normally used by humans a computer sees `0.1` more or less like you see `0.3333333333333...` (and you dont' have infinte paper to write down all those threes).

You should follow the advice of ybungalobill, and by the way to me seems that your problem would be a lot easier to solve using a different approach based on integer arithmetic and the modulo operator.

```
if (index % 10 == 0)
```

seems to be the test you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++){

        if ( (int) (10 * (  0.1 * (double)index))  ==  (int)(10 * ( int ) ( 0.1 * (double)index ) ) )
        {
                 std::cout << "equal";
        }
}
```

Comment: -1: Why not trying to change the name of the variable from `index` to `i`? Why not trying to use `stdio.h` instead of `iostream`? Why not trying to use `unsigned` instead of `int`? ... "try" (if we exclude a few areas like performance or user interface design) has no meaning in programming. Think and then do, or do not. There's no try.

Comment: say what you will, i tried and it worked :) RAD programming is code first think later anyway. It all depends what you are doing...

Comment: This is because you don't have a correct concept of "working" (that doesn't mean that you found at least one case where it gave the results that in your opinion are correct). And while "try and see" is bad in general for programming it's a true suicide in C++, because the language will punish your errors with undefined behavior daemons and not with runtime error angels.

Comment: I agree with you, but i cannot compile the code in my head taking in accaunt compiler differences. That is why i try. Another alternative is to read both compiler documentation to find a reason. This of course can take months.